# Laravel Manager S3 Bucket got Forbidden (403) Response

Tags: laravel, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I set S3 Bucket as file storage, it is work for read/write through input file. But I got problem when integrating it with [Laravel File Manager](https://github.com/UniSharp/laravel-filemanager). When trying to visit `/laravel-filemanager/demo`, I got error:

> Unable to write file at location: files/1/. Error executing "PutObject" on "https://BUCKET.s3.ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/files/1/"; AWS HTTP error: Client error: `PUT https://BUCKET.s3.ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/files/1/` resulted in a `403 Forbidden` response: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> <Error><Code>AccessDenied</Code><Message>Access Denied</Message><RequestId>6YBFTW (truncated...) AccessDenied (client): Access Denied - <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> <Error><Code>AccessDenied</Code><Message>Access Denied</Message>**********</RequestId>************158RzcM/Al09WYc=

Here is the bucket policy:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Id": "Policy1667963254419",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Stmt1667963249364",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": [
                "s3:DeleteObject",
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:PutObject"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::BUCKET/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

I think the permission is right. Any idea?

Comment: Does laravel has access to access and secret keys?

Comment: @Riz, yes.  I need to make it public using ACL, and it works.

Comment: Did you attatch the bucket policy to the correct AWS user?

Comment: Have you cleared your cache? `php artisan config:cache`

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example reference that I use for a working production app: (although I imagine you don't need the s3-object-lambda)

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:*",
                "s3-object-lambda:*"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::MY_BUCKET",
                "arn:aws:s3:::MY_BUCKET/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Make sure you have credentials for a user that has that policy attached (ideally a user with only those credentials):

Link just replace `USER_XYZ` with your user:
https://us-east-1.console.aws.amazon.com/iam/home#/users/USER_XYZ?section=security_credentials

To validate whether it is your access key that is incorrect or if it is your Laravel setup, I would test your access using the AWS CLI https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/qradar-how-test-credential-permissions-aws-command-line-interface